# For Loop Creates An Infinite Loop When It Detects A Non-Alphabetical Character

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

During the for loop iteration i does not get incremented if a non-alphabetical character is detected in the if statement.

The nonnumeric function returns true if the character is non-alphabetical else it returns false. When I tested the code inside the for loop I had the console print out the value of i. Whenever the code reached a non-alphabetical character i would not get incremented and thus would create an infinite for loop.

```
function isUpper(str){
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i).toUpperCase()){
      if(!nonnumeric(str.charAt(i))){
        return true;
      };
    };
  };
  return false;
};
```

I expect it to return true if there is an uppercase character inside the string. If there is not an uppercase character in the string I expect it to return false.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the results. Can you show how you came to the conclusion that an infinite loop is occurring? Nothing in said for loop would stop `i` from incrementing without also stopping the loop.

Comment: the loop will run through N times where N is the length of str.  To make this inf, you would need to add to the string at a rate >= the pace of iteration as each iteration str.length is computed.

Comment: Why does `nonnumeric()` return true if the character is non-alphabetic instead of non-numeric?

Comment: are you just trying to see if the whole string is upper case?

Comment: I see that you're not _declaring_ `i` here with `var` or `let`; is it possible that `nonnumeric` or something else is overwriting your global `i` variable, maybe? Maybe posing your `nonnumeric` function would help us out.

Comment: I can't believe I made such a dumb mistake. @Jacob Thanks for pointing it out. The issue was that I forgot to declare `i` with `let` and nonnumeric was overwriting the global variable `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking to see if an entire string is uppercase, you can do something much easier.

```js
function isUpper(str) {
  return /^[A-Z\s\W]+$/.test(str);
}

console.log(isUpper('ALL UPPER CASE'));
console.log(isUpper('ALL UPPER CASE! WITH ~@# STUFF'));
console.log(isUpper('THIS hAS ONE LOWER CASE CHARACTER'));
console.log(isUpper('THIS HAS 1 NUMBER'));
```

### Explanation

The regex checks if the entire string from start (`^`) to end (`$`) matches the characters enclosed in the `[]`, which is a range of from capital A through capital Z (`A-Z`, the special "space" character `\s`, and other non-word characters `\W`, matching one or more times. You could fine-tune this to make sure that it matches at least one capital letter, followed optionally by spaces, commas, exclamation points, etc. It all depends on your use cases and what the expected input vs. output would be

### EDIT

Hadn't read the last sentence under the code. If all you want is to check for an uppercase character somewhere in the string, you could simply have

```js
function isUpper(str) {
  return /[A-Z]/.test(str)
}

console.log(isUpper('ALL UPPER CASE'));
console.log(isUpper('ALL UPPER CASE! WITH ~@# STUFF'));
console.log(isUpper('THIS hAS ONE LOWER CASE CHARACTER'));
console.log(isUpper('THIS HAS 1 NUMBER'));
console.log(isUpper('this has no uppercase characters at all'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple things that I believe are causing the issue:

1. You're looking through each character in the string individually, then returning either true or false.  If your goal is to determine whether the string contains at least one uppercase letter, then you first need to iterate through the entire string.  Right now, if your first character isn't uppercase it won't return true and so will instantly return false.
2. When you iterate through the string you'll hit non-alpha characters like spaces and punctuation.  If you test whether a "lower case" period equals an "upper case" period, it'll evaluate to true, which could throw a false positive.

Solution:
I've changed the function a little bit.  Now, it iterates through the entire string and it uses a Regular Expression ("Regex") to determine if the value being tested is indeed a letter.  If it runs into a letter that's uppercase, the count is increased, allowing the code to go through the entire string.  We use the logical "&&" operator to accomplish two logical checks inside of our final if function.

How to improve:
You could make this code better by returning true as soon as the count is increased above 0, but I'll leave that up to you if you want.

EDIT: Moved the 2nd If statement into the for loop so that as soon as the condition is met it returns true, rather than having to loop through the entire string before checking.

```
function isUpper(str) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str.charAt(i)) && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      count += 1;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;

}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I have a small question about your code: what would happen for a string such as "THIs IS UPPER" ? Because from what I'm seeing it would still return true even though there is a lower-case character present. It would be easier to check for lowercase characters, and then flip the positions of the true/false in the returns.

Comment: From how I'm interpreting the poster's question, your example should return true.  If I read the 2nd to last sentence in the post, "I expect it to return true if there is an uppercase character inside the string", I interpret that as just one character needs to be uppercase for it to return true, not the entire string.

Comment: ah, I hadn't seen that, but you could edit your for statement so that it doesn't go through the entire string when it finds an upper case character. You could simply just have it `return true` instead of going through a string even though the condition of finding an uppercase character has been met.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I mentioned in my code that could be done.  Could put the 2nd if statement inside the for loop after the first if statement, which would then check if count has increased after every letter is considered.  I just wanted to avoid doing too much without explaining whats going on, for instance the entire thing could be achieved with 2 lines of Regex, but I'm not sure how much this person knows about that.  I'll edit the code to show that.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: this is just philosophical, but honestly if the OP doesn't know about regex, it's our job as the more senior developers/engineers to introduce them to it. If we don't present them with things that they don't know yet (especially things directly relevant to solving their issue) then we are not helping them grow.

Comment: Your paragraph #1 is wrong. `return false` is not inside the loop.

Comment: #2 is supposed to be addressed by the `nonnumeric()` function. Despite the name, it's suppose to tell if the character is alphabetic, so non-alphabetic characters will not return `true`.

Comment: As he mentioned in a comment, the problem is not with the algorithm, he just messed up variable scopes by not declaring `i` as a local variable in this function or `nonnumeric()`.